# Keycloak auth with Ajax

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, http, keycloak

I've a Keycloak server and I want to auth via http Ajax request, sending username + email to login. and signup new user. is that possible to create standalone web app to authorize user?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's not a good practice you can do that by enabling Direct Grant Access for your client, look for "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" in the documentation https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/content/server_admin/topics/sso-protocols/oidc.html

Comment: +1 for stressing that this is not good practice. Instead the app should redirect to the login page hosted by keycloak. The look and feel can be customised to match the app using Freemarker Templates.

Comment: Further to shonky linux user's comment: theming is discussed here - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#creating-a-theme